# Early printk in kernel seems not working as expected

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, boot

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.10.24), and I am trying to get the kernel log as early as possible, so I enabled the `CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK` in kernel configuration.

When the kernel is booted up with U-boot, instead of getting the kernel banner, the first kernel log I got is as follows,

```
....
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    2.243226] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    2.247565] printk: bootconsole [early0] disabled
......
```

It seemed that the early printk does NOT work as I expected.
The kernel command line is as follows,

```
console=ttyS0,115200 loglevel=8 init=/bin/bash root=ubi0:rootfs log_buf_len=32K
```

Is there any specific configuration required for the kernel to print its log at the earliest possible stage?

Answer (score 1):

[The help text for the `CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK` option](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/Kconfig.debug?h=v5.10.186#n1949) says:

> Say Y here if you want to have an early console using the kernel low-level debugging functions. **Add `earlyprintk` to your kernel parameters** to enable this console.

Your kernel command line does not include the `earlyprintk` parameter. Try adding it?

Also, the [early_printk.c for ARM](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/early_printk.c?h=v5.10.186) uses the [`printascii()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.186/source/arch/arm/kernel/debug.S#L83) function, which seems to be affected by the `CONFIG_DEBUG_UART_FLOW_CONTROL` option. If that option is set, does your serial console cable provide the CTS flow control signal to the embedded system?

There does not seem to be any UART initialization code, so the baud rate and other settings are probably still at the values u-boot has set.

Comment: I did add `earlyprintk=serial,ttyS0,115200,keep` into kernel commandline, but does NOT work.

Comment: Those parameters look like they are intended for the x86 version of the `earlyprintk`. The ARM version is a lot more rudimentary, and does not seem to process any parameters. It might require some patching to make it work on your specific embedded system.

Answer (score 1):

Thank telcoM for sharing his comments, which gave me tips to dig into the earlyprintk internal.

Then, I figured it out.
The `earlyprintk` driver is hard coded to use the first serial console, which is not connected in my system (it uses another serial port), so by changing the code to use the right serial port, `earlyprintk` can work as expected.

Next, I would check if the serial port could be configured for `earlyprintk` instead of hard coding.